# C# ClosedXML Table Theme list

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, closedxml

Is there any documentation or article listing the Table themes along with displaying the styles for excel workbooks in ClosedXML library. I am unable to find anything on this in their github documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Excel, go to the Home Tab and click in the Styles section "Format as Table".

Now you can hover your mouse over the various table styles and it will show you their names, which you can than use with ClosedXML.

Other office products likely have similar features that will allow you to see a list of themes.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the theme is determined by the application that opens the resulting file, i.e. Excel, LibreOffice Calc, etc. It's not a ClosedXML issue.

Comment: Yes also, the names provided in the styles property of the closedxml correspond to the same names as displayed in Table styles in excel on hovering over their previews